# What happens when you run `git add .git` in a Git repository?

Tags: git, git-add

While it seemed to do nothing, it gave no warning or error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually a relevant question; I admit I just did it. I dit it because I wanted to add `.gitignore` but tab completion stopped at `.git`, so by accident I did it. And I was (like you) worried "What did I destroy?".

Comment: I did it because I've been using GNU stow to install a `.git/info/exclude` file into a repository that I share with other people, and I wanted to put the stow package that contains this `.git` folder under version control.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Comment from Git source:

```
/*
 * Read a directory tree. We currently ignore anything but
 * directories, regular files and symlinks. That's because git
 * doesn't handle them at all yet. Maybe that will change some
 * day.
 *
 * Also, we ignore the name ".git" (even if it is not a directory).
 * That likely will not change.
 */
```

Experiment to see what happend if I create a  file `.git` and try to add it:
(on Windows I cannot create a file `.git` when there is already a `.git` folder. I also could have created a `.git` elsewhere in a sub directory, but wanted to try out `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` which I haven't used before. After all I am experimenting. This also allows me to show that I can add the git metadata folder as seen below)

```
git --git-dir="c:/test" init
touch blah
git --git-dir="c:/test" --work-tree="." add .
git --git-dir="c:/test" --work-tree="." status ( shows blah added)
touch .git
git --git-dir="c:/test" --work-tree="." add .git ( no output as usual)
git --git-dir="c:/test" --work-tree="." status ( only blah shown)
```

So yeah, `.git` - be it directory or file, is ignored by git.

And if I do something like below:

```
git --git-dir="c:/test" --work-tree="c:/test" add c:/test
```

all the meta files get added.

So again, it is only `.git` that is ignored not the git metadata folder (that you set via `--git-dir`) as far as I can see.

Comment: In which file/revision in the source did you find this comment?

Comment: Nevermind, found it -- https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe9122a35213827348c521a16ffd0cf2652c4ac5/dir.c#L1277

Comment: What do you mean by "the git metadata dir"? Isn't the directory you set with `--git-dir` your working directory?

Comment: But what happens if you try to add a file _in_ the `.git` directory? Then the name will not be ".git".

Answer (score 18):

Short answer: Nothing.

Long answer:

```
laptop:Projects ctcherry$ mkdir test
laptop:Projects ctcherry$ cd test
laptop:test ctcherry$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ctcherry/Projects/test/.git/
laptop:test ctcherry$ git add .git
laptop:test ctcherry$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
laptop:test ctcherry$
```